# Perl regex replace count

Tags: regex, perl

Is it possible to specify the maximum number of matches to replace. For instance if matching 'l' in "Hello World", would it be possible to replace the first 2 'l' characters, but not the third without looping?

Comment: you can with python `re.sub(repl, string[, count=0])`, but this, obviously, is not what you are after.

Comment: It might be the motivation needed to trade up to Python.

Comment: @Quick: Up? Surely, you mean down.

Comment: I like writing Perl, but I don't especially enjoy reading it back.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$str = "Hello world!";
$str =~ s/l/r/ for (1,2);
print $str;
```

I don't see what's so bad about looping.

Actually, here's a way:

```
$str="Hello world!"; 
$str =~ s/l/$i++ >= 2 ? "l": "r"/eg; 
print $str;
```

It's a loop, of sorts, since s///g works in a loopy way when you do this. But not a traditional loop.

Comment: How is the latter way "loopy"? It just traverses the string once, right?

Comment: @Tim Nordenfur: It evals each time it finds a match, but yes, only goes through the string once. You could do `while (/match/g)` to create a loop.

Comment: Every method is a loop.  There are explicit loops (the ones that look like 'while' or 'foreach', and implicit loops (the ones that don't have a name but occur behind the scenes.)  There's no traversal (even once) without an implicit loop.  It's just hidden in the /g clause of the RE engine.

Answer (score 9):

Here is one way.  This requires an external counter to be updated within the RE using a `(?{code})` block inside of a `(?(condition)true-sub-expression|false-sub-expression)` construct.  See [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) for an explanation.

```
use Modern::Perl;
use re qw/eval/; # Considered experimental.

my $string = 'Hello world!';

my $count = 2;

my $re =    qr/
                (l)
                (?(?{$count--})|(*FAIL))
            /x;

say "Looking for $count instances of 'l' in $string.";
my ( @found ) = $string =~ m/$re/g;
say "Found ", scalar @found, " instances of 'l': @found";
```

The output is:

```
Looking for 2 instances of 'l' in Hello world!
Found 2 instances of 'l': l l
```

Here's another test of the same regexp, but this time we're keeping track of the position of the matches just to prove it's matching the first two occurrences.

```
use Modern::Perl;
use strict;
use warnings;
use re qw/eval/; # Considered experimental.

my $string = 'Hello world!';

my $count = 2;
my $position = 0;

my $re =    qr/
                (l)(?{$position=pos})
                (?(?{$count--})|(*FAIL))
            /x;

while( $string =~ m/$re/g ) {
    say "Found $1 at ", $position;
}
```

And this time the output is:

```
Found l at 3
Found l at 4
```

I don't think I would recommend any of this.  If I were considering constraining matches to only one portion of a string, I would match against a `substr()` of the string.  But if you like to live on the edge, go ahead and have fun with this snippet.

Here it is in a substitution:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use strict;
use warnings;
use re qw/eval/; # Considered experimental.

my $string = 'Hello world!';
say "Before substitution $string";
my $count = 2;
my $re =    qr/
                (l)
                (?(?{$count--})|(*FAIL))
            /x;

 $string =~ s/$re/L/g;

 say "After substitution  $string";
```

And the output:

```
Before substitution Hello world!
After substitution  HeLLo world!
```

Comment: One note: I really wanted to run this through YAPE::Regex::Explain to show what was happening, but unfortunately it wasn't producing an accurate description of what is going on.

Comment: Another comment, if anyone's still reading:  Any method that involves a counter embedded within the regexp itself is probably going to be sensitive to backtracking by the RE engine.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. You will need to perform the substitutions in a loop of some kind.

Comment: `@re = qw(l l); s/(l)/shift @re || $1/eg;`

Comment: That's cute, but its utility is somewhat limited to only the most trivial of regex patterns. The version you posted in your answer is much more useful.